# How to share folders/files with other git repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules

We would like to share certain folders/files with other git repositories (like externals in SVN). What is the best way to source with other repositories but only part of the source (specific folders/files)?

For example, repository1 will use some folders/files (not the entire repository source) from repository2 and repository3, and it may that another repository will use some other/same folders/files.

Comment: If the files are distributed somewhere in the source code, that is not the easiest to do. If they are in a certain folder or you can move them into a common place then why not use a package manager, like node or NuGet?

Comment: use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: Using submodule will share the entire folders/files (whole source tree) and we would like to take only part of the repository. We would like only the specific folder/file

Comment: `git` focuses on versioning the entirety of your project, and isn't geared towards sharing only parts of it. This is why people (and I am part of them) will very likely guide you to group those files and folders in a clearly identifiable place (e.g : one single directory) and share that place (e.g : as a submodule).

Comment: To make your use case more specific : can you describe what kind of folders/files you wish to share ? for example : would they form a shared library in a code base ? or would they contain configuration parameters and secrets ? or the declaration part of some API ? or something else ?

Comment: shared library in a code base

Answer (score 2):

There is `git subtree` and `git submodule`

`git subtree` allow you to insert a copy of any repository as a subdirectory of another one. It is one of several ways Git projects can inject and manage project dependencies. It stores the external dependencies in regular commits. Git subtrees provide clean integration points, so they're easier to revert.

whereas

`git submodules` are in its default package that enable Git repositories to be nested within other repositories. To be accurate, the Git submodule points to a specific commit on the child repository.

a good tutorial for you,
https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407

commands to help you create a submodule
https://opensource.com/article/20/5/git-submodules-subtrees

Comment: The folders we need to share are parts of different repositories. Is there a way to create submodule from a folder in the specific repository?

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting your own Git server, you may use [Git X-Modules](https://gitmodules.com). Unlike submodules, subtrees etc. it's a server-side tool, that allows selecting certain paths (to files and folders) instead of embedding the complete repository.
Also, all synchronization is done in the background (on the server), so for end-users a synchronized folder in their repository is just like any other folder - they don't have to run special commands, etc.
Git X-Modules was intended to fill the gap in Git for the people who migrated from SVN and missed svn:externals :-)

Disclaimer: I am a part of the team.

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have questions or need help: https://support.tmatesoft.com/c/x-modules/8